# Azure devops deploy .net core to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, azure-artifacts

I am using azure devops for CI/CD of a .net core application

I am doing a nuget restore/build solution test etc followed by "Publish Artifact like below". All fairly standard

[image]

I want to deploy this the AWS elastic beanstalk, and have the following task setup in Azure Devops..

I have tried a number of things but not sure how to get the .net core application deployed to aws beanstalk... The problem i believe is with the location of zip file. what should this be? - Is there anything else needed to be done? It just errors trying to created deployment bundle in the "Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk" task (btw aws connection etc is working fine)

[image]

Comment: Try `$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)`

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT - yes, I have managed to get it working thanks to your answer. However it still took more time to figure exactly what i needed. had to use dotnet publish as you mentioned,. I'll provide a more detailed response as an answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure devops deploy .net core to AWS elastic beanstalk

It depends on the output of the previous dotnet publish.

You could get the info from the `Deployment Bundle Type`:

```
ASP.NET Core (Source: dotnet publish)
```

As you can see the source is from `dotnet publish` task.

Then, the output location of the next option `Published Application Path` should be based on previous build steps placed the deployment artifacts. It should be the path and filename of the `.zip` file containing the artifacts.

You can check the details info from the document:

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy Application Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/elastic-beanstalk-deploy.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full [tutorial on how to do Elastic Beanstalk deployment using Azure DevOps](https://cloudopian.com/blog/azure-devops-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk/)

You can also use [this PowerShell script](https://github.com/cloudopian/azure-devops-on-aws/blob/master/MyTigerApp/ElasticBeanstalkDeployment/AdvancedDeployment.ps1) to automate the end to end deployment instead of using Azure DevOps plugins. It gives your more flexibility on what you can do with your deployments